# How to get a parseJSON in Android through php

Tags: json, parsing, android-intent, expert-system

I have a part of code from php like this. Any two table tbl_gejala for change a sentence and tbl_hormon for move a Layout. Tbl_gejala with $id_g and tbl_hormon $id_h. and this php called by gejala.php. 
I use 2 choice for this application, yes or  no. $jawab == 1 for yes and $jawab == o for no.

```
$id_g = $_GET['id_g'];
$jawab = $_GET['a']; 

 $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die ('Tidak bisa menampilkan');
mysql_select_db('hormon', $link) or die('Tidak bisa select');

if($id_g == 1 && $jawab == 1){
  $query = "SELECT * from tbl_gejala where id_g = 3";

  }elseif($id_g == 3 && $jawab == 1){
  $query = "SELECT * from tbl_gejala where id_g = 5";

}elseif($id_g == 5 && $jawab == 1){
//intent activity and parseJSON with table hormon
$query = "SELECT * from tbl_hormon where id_h = 16";

}elseif($id_g == 5 && $jawab == 0){
$query = "SELECT * from tbl_gejala where id_g = 10";

  }elseif($id_g == 10 && $jawab == 1){
   $query = "SELECT * from tbl_hormon where id_h = 1";

  }elseif($id_g == 10 && $jawab == 0){
  $query = "SELECT * from tbl_hormon where id_h = 7";
```

I want to parseJSON with gejala.php in konsultasi.class
I have try this coding, but any problem by logic error. This coding like this:

```
void parseJSON(String response) {
        try {
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);
            listArray = new ArrayList<ListModel>();

            JSONArray jArray = json.getJSONArray("Hormon");
            log("lenght: " + jArray.length());
            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jData = jArray.getJSONObject(i);             
                if(idPert.equals("5")&&yes.equals("1")  || 
                   idPert.equals("7")&&yes.equals("1")  ||
                   idPert.equals("11")&&yes.equals("1") ||
                   idPert.equals("11")&&no.equals("0") ||
                   idPert.equals("10")&&yes.equals("1") ||
                   idPert.equals("16")&&yes.equals("1") ||
                   idPert.equals("19")&&yes.equals("1") ||
                   idPert.equals("20")&&yes.equals("1") ||
                   idPert.equals("20")&&no.equals("0") ||
                   idPert.equals("8")&&yes.equals("1") ||
                   idPert.equals("17")&&yes.equals("1") ||
                   idPert.equals("17")&&no.equals("0") ||
                   idPert.equals("6")&&yes.equals("1") ||
                   idPert.equals("13")&&yes.equals("1") ||
                   idPert.equals("13")&&no.equals("0") ||
                   idPert.equals("12")&&yes.equals("1") ||
                   idPert.equals("14")&&yes.equals("1") ||
                   idPert.equals("15")&&yes.equals("1") ||
                   idPert.equals("18")&&yes.equals("1") ||
                   idPert.equals("21")&&yes.equals("1") ||
                   idPert.equals("22")&&yes.equals("1") ||
                   idPert.equals("10")&&no.equals("0")) {

                    id_h = jData.getString("id_h"); 
                    nm_penyakit = jData.getString("nm_penyakit"); 
                    definisi = jData.getString("definisi"); 
                    gejala = jData.getString("gejala"); 
                    penyebab = jData.getString("penyebab"); 
                    solusi = jData.getString("solusi"); 
                    gambar = jData.getString("gambar"); 
                    munculPenyakit = true;

                }else{
                    idPert = jData.getString("id_g");
                    pertanyaan = jData.getString("gejala2")+"?";
                    munculPenyakit = false;                     
                }   
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Please help me, thanks a lot before.